# Bullets without itemize ignoring spacing

Tags: spacing

Easy question for those in the know :)
I can produce a itemised list like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item banana
\item mango
\item Meg Ryan
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

But when I use text bullets the space between the bullet and the text is ignored

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Steven Segal \textbullet is  \textbullet a \textbullet really \textbullet bad shot!
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How are these two related? If you need itemize inline with your text, you can use paralist package which handles the spacing automaically.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to insert a space after it, using

```
Steven Segal \textbullet\ is  \textbullet\ a \textbullet\ really \textbullet\ bad shot!
```

Also, you don't need the `enumitem` package for this neither for `itemize` environment.

Comment: That simple. That's cool. I was worried it would be \secretspace or some command unknown to me. Thank you.

Comment: aha secret space is actually `\-` Well done me.